# Create new command for plugin for eclipse, which cannot be runned twice (2 instance)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have the plugin for eclipse. I should create new command.
All information for command will be collected in popup (SWT, but i haven't the special requirements, information can be collected by other way)

After starting the command will write logs in console (I made it)

But i don't know how to forbid start new command when current command not finished.
If command will crashed - how show information about crashing? (i made all work in new thread).

I haven't special requirements for this task and I can change implementation, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

In this case we should use "Task" and "Monitor". When task will be in process we will show "progress monitor".